# Colorbox iframe not opening up on the same page

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using colorbox iframe to open a popup to an external page. In the HTML page, there is some HTML content and some content from javascript ( after an AJAX call) to append to a HTML ul tag.

Something like
    
    // Initialize colorbox 
    $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"}); // this is in the     document.ready function 
    
    // Main page

```
<ul>
</ul>
</div>
<script>
---Some AJAx QUERY 
-- USE THE DATA FROM ajax QUERY TO CREATE A NEW <UL>
var ul_append="<a class=iframe href=#> </a>"
$(ul_append).appendTo('#grid10 ul');
</script>
```

So the issue I am seeing is that when I click the  tag formed by ul_append, it gives me this error

```
$close.html(settings.close).show is not a function
$close.html(settings.close).show();
```

"

The earlier one works just fine ...Any clues??

Comment: I am not sure why some elements are showing up as class=iframe cboxElement and others as class=iframe ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the ajax content you are loading also contains jQuery.  This 2nd version of jQuery is replacing the jQuery library you originally loaded and extended with the colorbox plugin, which causes problems when attempting to use it.

Comment: Thanks Jack .. however I am not using. The AJAX query returns a JSON element and the data returned is being used as data[counter].<variable> to create the ul_append ...  I'll double check though .. I changed couple of things around. Now the ul_append elements are of the class=iframe not class="iframe cboxElement" and hence no popup.